# Вопрос по работе с массивами и запросом

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы, битрикс

я новичок в PHP. Я знаю, что вопрос наверное глупый, но к сожалению информации настолько много, что я в ней потерялся. 
Есть такой код:

```
public function newpublic($basket_content)
{
    foreach ($basket_content as $newids)
    {
        $proids[] = $newids['PRODUCT_ID'];
    }
    AddMessage2Log(print_r($proids, true));
    return $proids;
}
public function searchcode($val)
{
    global $DB;
    $results = $DB->Query("SELECT `VALUE` FROM `b_iblock_element_property` WHERE `IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID`='10' and `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`= self::searchcode");
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $results->Fetch())
    {
    $arr = $row;
    }
    $arr = unserialize($arr['VALUE']);
    $frontpadart = $arr[$val]['IIKO_ID'];
    return $frontpadart;
}
```

В первой функции ***newpublic*** я получаю нужные мне ID.
Они такого формата:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 610
    [1] => 610
    [2] => 611
    [3] => 611
    [4] => 612
    [5] => 612
)
```

Мне нужно с помощью этих ID, получить другие ID запросом в БД.

```
$DB->Query("SELECT `VALUE` FROM `b_iblock_element_property` WHERE `IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID`='10' and `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID`= self::searchcode");
```

Но так как в массиве много ID, то значит нужно повторять много раз запрос?
Ведь мне нужно получить ***$frontpadart = $arr[$val]['IIKO_ID'];*** для каждого из этих элементов. Спасибо всем заранее!

Comment: Конвертируешь массив в CSV-строку, заменяешь равенство на `field IN (список)`, вставляешь список (без обрамляющих кавычек!)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно перечислять все, передайте их в запрос все сразу:

```
$sql = "SELECT `VALUE` FROM `b_iblock_element_property` WHERE `IBLOCK_PROPERTY_ID`='10' and `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` in (1,2,3,10,50,100);
$DB->Query($sql);
```